# JQuery FadeIn and Add class when scrolling past div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, umbraco

I have some JQuery that fades in my filter bar and adds padding to the content to compensate if the user scrolls past the `#contentPageSection` div.

If the filter bar is hidden, it should remove the padding but upon scrolling the padding is constantly being added. Not sure how to get around this.

Here's a video of my issue:

http://recordit.co/xyxlJx7xW7

HTML:

```
<div id="column2">
  <div style="background-image: url(&quot;/media/1122/caroline-g_wide.jpg?alpha=50&quot;); height: 983px;" class="fullSizeImage smoothScrolling" id="landingImage">
    <div style="position: relative;">
      <div id="scrollingArrows" style="top: 923px;"> <a href="#contentPageSection">
        <div class="arrow arrowHidden"></div>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        </a> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middleAlignedContainer">
      <h1>Careers</h1>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-image: url(/media/1122/caroline-g_wide.jpg?alpha=50)" class="fullSizeImage smoothScrolling " id="smallTitleImage"> <a href="#landingImage">
    <h2>Careers</h2>
    </a> </div>
  <div id="contentPageSection">
    <div class="row contentGrid" id="careers" style="height: 938px;">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <ul id="jobList">
          <li class="job jobRow row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1">
              <div class="jobTitle nameColumn"> <a title="Read more" href="/en/careers/canada/solar-project-manager/">
                <h3>Solar Project Manager</h3>
                </a> </div>
              <div id="tags">
                <div class="tag typeofRoleColumn"> <a onclick="OnlyShowJobsWith('Construction'); return false;" href="#" title="Only show jobs on Construction">Construction</a>
                  <p title="Remove jobs on Construction" data-role="remove" class="mdi-content-clear right"> <span onclick="HideJobsWith('Construction');">X</span> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="tag locationColumn"> <a onclick="OnlyShowJobsWith('Canada'); return false;" href="#" title="Only show jobs in Canada">Canada</a>
                  <p title="Remove jobs in Canada" data-role="remove" class="mdi-content-clear right"> <span onclick="HideJobsWith('Canada');">X</span> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="tag contractTypeColumn"> <a onclick="OnlyShowJobsWith('Full-Time'); return false;" href="#" title="Only show Full-Time jobs">Full-Time</a>
                  <p title="Remove Full-Time jobs" data-role="remove" class="mdi-content-clear right"> <span onclick="HideJobsWith('Full-Time');">X</span> </p>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1"> <a title="Read more" href="/en/careers/canada/solar-project-manager/">
              <p><strong>Description</strong>: The Solar Project Manager will manage Wind farm/Solar farm construction projects in Ontario Canada.</p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p><strong>Responsibilities:</strong></p>
              <ol>
                <li>Client satisfaction, budget control, profitability, contract compliance, problem resolution and project personnel management</li>
                <li>Organize, execute and coordinate wor…</li>
              </ol>
              </a> </div>
          </li>
          <li class="job jobRow row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1">
              <div class="jobTitle nameColumn"> <a title="Read more" href="/en/careers/canada/site-civil-inspector/">
                <h3>Site Civil Inspector</h3>
                </a> </div>
              <div id="tags">
                <div class="tag typeofRoleColumn"> <a onclick="OnlyShowJobsWith('Construction'); return false;" href="#" title="Only show jobs on Construction">Construction</a>
                  <p title="Remove jobs on Construction" data-role="remove" class="mdi-content-clear right"> <span onclick="HideJobsWith('Construction');">X</span> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="tag locationColumn"> <a onclick="OnlyShowJobsWith('Canada'); return false;" href="#" title="Only show jobs in Canada">Canada</a>
                  <p title="Remove jobs in Canada" data-role="remove" class="mdi-content-clear right"> <span onclick="HideJobsWith('Canada');">X</span> </p>
                </div>
                <div class="tag contractTypeColumn"> <a onclick="OnlyShowJobsWith('Full-Time'); return false;" href="#" title="Only show Full-Time jobs">Full-Time</a>
                  <p title="Remove Full-Time jobs" data-role="remove" class="mdi-content-clear right"> <span onclick="HideJobsWith('Full-Time');">X</span> </p>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1"> <a title="Read more" href="/en/careers/canada/site-civil-inspector/">
              <p><strong>Description:</strong></p>
              <p>Carry out site civil inspections to support the project and client. Control the civil subcontractors and suppliers to ensure they meet contractual requirements. The role is instrumental in delivering on time cost effective projects.</p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p><strong>Responsibilities:</strong></p>
              <ol>
                <li>Inspect all civil work in a …</li>
              </ol>
              </a> </div>
          </li>
          <li class="job jobRow row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1">
              <div class="jobTitle nameColumn">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-1">
                  <div class="jobTitle nameColumn"> <a title="Read more" href="/en/careers/united-states/solar-manager-electrical-i-ii/">
                    <h3>Solar Manager - Electrical I &amp; II</h3>
                    </a> </div>
                  <div id="tags">
                    <div class="tag typeofRoleColumn"> <a onclick="OnlyShowJobsWith('Construction'); return false;" href="#" title="Only show jobs on Construction">Construction</a>
                      <p title="Remove jobs on Construction" data-role="remove" class="mdi-content-clear right"> <span onclick="HideJobsWith('Construction');">X</span> </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tag locationColumn"> <a onclick="OnlyShowJobsWith('USA'); return false;" href="#" title="Only show jobs in USA">USA</a>
                      <p title="Remove jobs in USA" data-role="remove" class="mdi-content-clear right"> <span onclick="HideJobsWith('USA');">X</span> </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tag contractTypeColumn"> <a onclick="OnlyShowJobsWith('Full-Time'); return false;" href="#" title="Only show Full-Time jobs">Full-Time</a>
                      <p title="Remove Full-Time jobs" data-role="remove" class="mdi-content-clear right"> <span onclick="HideJobsWith('Full-Time');">X</span> </p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-offset-1"> <a title="Read more" href="/en/careers/united-states/solar-manager-electrical-i-ii/">
                  <p>Summary:</p>
                  <p>Manage the daily activities of the electrical construction on a large scale wind, solar, transmission, battery storage project sites.</p>
                  <p>Specific duties:</p>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Leadership&nbsp;Accountabilities:&nbsp; Identify, deploy, and manage a high-performing team needed to accomplish business objectives. Provide a p…</li>
                  </ul>
                  </a> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="filter">
        <div class="showSideBar careers_filter" id="filter_overlay" style="">
          <div id="toggleSidebar"><span class="filterHideButton rightArrow"></span></div>
          <div data-mcs-theme="light-thick" class="mCustomScrollbar _mCS_2 mCS_no_scrollbar" id="filters">
            <div class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-light-thick mCSB_vertical mCSB_inside" id="mCSB_2" style="max-height: 10494px;" tabindex="0">
              <div dir="ltr" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0;" class="mCSB_container mCS_y_hidden mCS_no_scrollbar_y" id="mCSB_2_container">
                <div class="filtertype" id="location"> 
                  <!-- Location List -->
                  <div class="slideTitle">
                    <h3>Location</h3>
                    <span class="filterTitleArrow downArrow"></span></div>
                  <div class="slideDetails">
                    <ul>
                      <span class="checkallcareers" onclick="toggleAll('#location', checked);"><img src="/images/selectAll.png" class="mCS_img_loaded">Toggle All</span>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Australia" id="Australia" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Australia', 'locationColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Australia">Australia (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Canada" id="Canada" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Canada', 'locationColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Canada">Canada (6)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Chile" id="Chile" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Chile', 'locationColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Chile">Chile (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="France" id="France" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('France', 'locationColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="France">France (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Germany" id="Germany" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Germany', 'locationColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Germany">Germany (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Japan" id="Japan" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Japan', 'locationColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Japan">Japan (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Sweden" id="Sweden" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Sweden', 'locationColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Sweden">Sweden (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Turkey" id="Turkey" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Turkey', 'locationColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Turkey">Turkey (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="UK" id="UK" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('UK', 'locationColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="UK">UK (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="USA" id="USA" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('USA', 'locationColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="USA">USA (37)</label>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="filtertype" id="contractType"> 
                  <!-- Contract Type List -->
                  <div class="slideTitle">
                    <h3>Contract Type</h3>
                    <span class="filterTitleArrow rightArrow"></span></div>
                  <div class="slideDetails">
                    <ul>
                      <span class="checkallcareers" onclick="toggleAll('#contractType');"><img src="/images/selectAll.png" class="mCS_img_loaded">Toggle All</span>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Consultant" id="Consultant" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Consultant', 'contractTypeColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Consultant">Consultant (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Contract" id="Contract" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Contract', 'contractTypeColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Contract">Contract (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Full-Time" id="Full-Time" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Full-Time', 'contractTypeColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Full-Time">Full-Time (42)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Part-Time" id="Part-Time" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Part-Time', 'contractTypeColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Part-Time">Part-Time (1)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Permanent" id="Permanent" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Permanent', 'contractTypeColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Permanent">Permanent (0)</label>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="filtertype" id="typeOfRole"> 
                  <!-- Type of Role List -->
                  <div class="slideTitle">
                    <h3>Type of Role</h3>
                    <span class="filterTitleArrow rightArrow"></span></div>
                  <div class="slideDetails">
                    <ul>
                      <span class="checkallcareers" onclick="toggleAll('#typeOfRole');"><img src="/images/selectAll.png" class="mCS_img_loaded">Toggle All</span>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Asset Management" id="AssetManagement" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Asset Management','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="AssetManagement">Asset Management (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Construction" id="Construction" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Construction','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Construction">Construction (21)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Development" id="Development" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Development','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Development">Development (3)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Engineering" id="Engineering" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Engineering','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Engineering">Engineering (7)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Finance" id="Finance" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Finance','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Finance">Finance (1)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Generation" id="Generation" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Generation','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Generation">Generation (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Health &amp; Safety" id="HealthSafety" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Health &amp; Safety','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="HealthSafety">Health &amp; Safety (2)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Human Resources" id="HumanResources" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Human Resources','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="HumanResources">Human Resources (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="IT" id="IT" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('IT','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="IT">IT (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Marketing" id="Marketing" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Marketing','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Marketing">Marketing (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Offshore" id="Offshore" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Offshore','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Offshore">Offshore (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Onshore" id="Onshore" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Onshore','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Onshore">Onshore (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Operations" id="Operations" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Operations','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Operations">Operations (2)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Procurement" id="Procurement" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Procurement','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Procurement">Procurement (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Project Delivery" id="ProjectDelivery" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Project Delivery','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="ProjectDelivery">Project Delivery (4)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Software" id="Software" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Software','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Software">Software (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Solar" id="Solar" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Solar','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Solar">Solar (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Storage" id="Storage" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Storage','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Storage">Storage (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Strategy" id="Strategy" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Strategy','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Strategy">Strategy (0)</label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Technical" id="Technical" name="checkbox" checked="" class="css-checkbox" onchange="ShowJobsWith('Technical','typeofRoleColumn');">
                        <label class="css-label" for="Technical">Technical (3)</label>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mCSB_scrollTools mCSB_2_scrollbar mCS-light-thick mCSB_scrollTools_vertical" id="mCSB_2_scrollbar_vertical" style="display: none;">
                <div class="mCSB_draggerContainer">
                  <div oncontextmenu="return false;" style="position: absolute; min-height: 30px; top: 0px;" class="mCSB_dragger" id="mCSB_2_dragger_vertical">
                    <div class="mCSB_dragger_bar" style="line-height: 30px;"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mCSB_draggerRail"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <div class="left">
        <div id="facebook" class="socialLink"> <img src="/images/icons/facebook.gif">
          <ul class="footerCountriesList">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/RESamericas" target="_blank">
            <li> <img src="/images/flags/usa.png"> <span>Americas</span> </li>
            </a> <a href="https://www.facebook/RES_France" target="_blank">
            <li> <img src="/images/flags/fr.png"> <span>France</span> </li>
            </a> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/resltd" target="_blank">
            <li> <img src="/images/flags/en.png"> <span>UK</span> </li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="twitter" class="socialLink"> <img src="/images/icons/twitter.gif">
          <ul class="footerCountriesList">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/RES_Americas" target="_blank">
            <li> <img src="/images/flags/usa.png"> <span>Americas</span> </li>
            </a> <a href="https://twitter.com/RES_France" target="_blank">
            <li> <img src="/images/flags/fr.png"> <span>France</span> </li>
            </a> <a href="https://twitter.com/RESGroup" target="_blank">
            <li> <img src="/images/flags/en.png"> <span>UK</span> </li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="linkedin" class="socialLink"> <img src="/images/icons/linkedin.gif">
          <ul class="footerCountriesList">
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/res-americas" target="_blank">
            <li> <img src="/images/flags/usa.png"> <span>Americas</span> </li>
            </a> <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/RES_France" target="_blank">
            <li> <img src="/images/flags/fr.png"> <span>France</span> </li>
            </a> <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/res-group" target="_blank">
            <li> <img src="/images/flags/en.png"> <span>UK</span> </li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="youtube" class="socialLink"> <img src="/images/icons/youtube.gif">
          <ul class="footerCountriesList">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/RESAMERICASINC" target="_blank">
            <li> <img src="/images/flags/usa.png"> <span>Americas</span> </li>
            </a> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/RESGroupLtd" target="_blank">
            <li> <img src="/images/flags/en.png"> <span>UK</span> </li>
            </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2015  Renewable Energy Systems Ltd. All rights reserved | <a href="/en/terms-of-use/">Terms of Use</a> | <a href="/en/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="/en/cookies/">Cookies</a> | <a href="/en/sitemap">SiteMap</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the `JQuery` that deals with the scrolling:

```
// Show filter bar when scrolled past the main image.
$(function(){
    var scrollTimer = null;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
            var st = $(this).scrollTop();
            var topOfTheDiv = $("#contentPageSection").offset().top;
            if(st > topOfTheDiv) {
                $('.careers_filter').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
                $('.careers_filter').stop().fadeIn(150);
                // add padding right to content when sidebar is shown - to avoid overlapping
                $(".contentGrid:first-child").addClass('toggleFilterPadding');
            }else{
                $('.careers_filter').stop().fadeOut(150);
                // remove padding right to content when sidebar is hidden
                $(".contentGrid:first-child").removeClass('toggleFilterPadding');
                }
        }

        if (scrollTimer) {
            clearTimeout(scrollTimer);   // clear any previous pending timer
        }
        scrollTimer = setTimeout(caughtScrollPosition, 100);   // set new timer
        updateNavigation();
    });
})
```

Here's the JQuery that deals with the hiding of the filter bar:

```
// hide or show the sidebar
    if($(window).width() <= 992) {
        $("#filter_overlay").removeClass('showSideBar').addClass('hideSideBar');
        $("#filter_overlay").children().children("span").removeClass('rightArrow').addClass('leftArrow');
    }

    $('.filterHideButton').on('click', function(){
        $("#filter_overlay").toggleClass('showSideBar').toggleClass('hideSideBar');
        $(".contentGrid:first-child").toggleClass('toggleFilterPadding');
        $("#filter_overlay").children("#toggleSidebar").children("span").toggleClass('leftArrow').toggleClass('rightArrow');

    });
});
```

Comment: You could cut and paste code from the view source or via the browser inspector?

Comment: Good point :) Added in the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its because you don't stop the padding from being added once it has been added. Once you get to the point of adding the padding it will always enter that if block on every scroll event until `st` is less than `topOfTheDiv` by scrolling back up. You can use a semaphore for something like this:

```
// Show filter bar when scrolled past the main image.
$(function(){
    var scrollTimer = null;
    var paddingAdded = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
            var st = $(this).scrollTop();
            var topOfTheDiv = $("#contentPageSection").offset().top;
            if(st > topOfTheDiv && !paddingAdded) {
                $('.careers_filter').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
                $('.careers_filter').stop().fadeIn(150);
                // add padding right to content when sidebar is shown - to avoid overlapping
                $(".contentGrid:first-child").addClass('toggleFilterPadding');
                paddingAdded = true;
            }
            if(st <= topOfTheDiv && paddingAdded) {
                $('.careers_filter').stop().fadeOut(150);
                // remove padding right to content when sidebar is hidden
                $(".contentGrid:first-child").removeClass('toggleFilterPadding');
                paddingAdded = false;
            }
        } <-- extra bracket

        if (scrollTimer) {
            clearTimeout(scrollTimer);   // clear any previous pending timer
        }
        scrollTimer = setTimeout(caughtScrollPosition, 100);   // set new timer
        updateNavigation();
    });
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o62Lchjm/

Comment: Makes sense what you are saying but unfortunately the example doesn't work. The side bar doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Actually there is typo in your code I believe. An extra bracket. Should the scrollTimer if be inside the scroll callback? Updated answer pointing to extra bracket.

Comment: @Madness Added a fiddle with extra code breaking bracket removed. Is this something like you expect? Obviously much CSS missing here.

Comment: Thanks Atheist! It works great. I just had to add another check to the 2nd if statement (&& $("#filter_overlay").hasClass('showSideBar')). Otherwise it was adding padding when the sidebar was hidden but you scroll above the image. (confusing stuff!)

Comment: @Madness Cool! Glad you got it working. Happy coding!